# SQL - two WORKERS one TIME filtering

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello masters of stackoverflow. I am in need of SQL help.

The situation: Need to filter out workers and add-up how long they worked.

database :

```
worker1    worker2    time_spent_in_seconds
X                     60
X          Y          60
Z          X          60
```

Condision: if worker1 and worker2 worked together their time is divided by 2
Result that i expect to get:

```
X=120
Y=30
Z=30
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far, SO Padawan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try below way by using union all

```
    select worker,sum(val) from 
    (   select worker1 as worker , case when worker2 is not null
     then  time_spent/2 else time_spent end as val from test
    union all
    select worker2 , case when worker2 is not null
     then  time_spent/2 else time_spent end as val from test
    ) t where worker is not null
    group by worker

worker  sum(val)
X       120
Y       30
Z       30
```

[Demo link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3KhBUVSQckeGXRheVPstt/1)

Comment: Thank you . Works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a switch function for this

```
SELECT worker1, worker2, 
CASE WHEN worker2 is not null
     THEN (time_spent / 2)
     ELSE time_spent  END as time_spent
FROM test;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h3KhBUVSQckeGXRheVPstt/0

Comment: have you seen your output in fiddle - it shows 60 for X but it should be 120 for X

Comment: @fa06 X appears 3 times, as 60, 30 and 30. making it 120. He will need to grab those rows for x and add them up